# invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Tags: r, classification, text-classification, naivebayes, document-classification

It is the error message on the topic. I am getting this error when I try to run naive.bayes classifier. Here is the summary of my train data:

```
'data.frame':   7269 obs. of  193 variables:
 $ pid       : int  2 4 5 7 10 11 14 18 25 31 ...
 $ acquir    : int  0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addit     : int  0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ agre      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ agreement : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ also      : int  1 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ american  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ announc   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ annual    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 ...
 $ approv    : int  0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ april     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ bank      : int  0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ base      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 .
 .
 $... all of them are integer, except the class column
 .
 .
 $ class     : Factor w/ 10 levels "acq","corn","crude",..: 1 1 4 4 9 1 4 3 1 4 ...
```

And this is the `naive.bayes()` line:

```
model <- naiveBayes(as.factor(class) ~ ., data = as.matrix(train), laplace = 3)
```

Can anyone tell me why it is happening?:

```
Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Comment: Eventually your data is converted to character because of `as.matrix(train)`. Try `model <- naiveBayes(class ~ ., data=train, laplace = 3)` or eventually `model <- naiveBayes(train$class ~ ., data=train[, -c("class")], laplace = 3)`

Comment: @jogo It worked! Thanks! I wanna accept your answer but how?

Comment: I made it an answer now. Did also the first variant work or only the second?

Comment: I just tried the first one. And it worked. Didn't try others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually your data is converted to character because of `as.matrix(train)`. Try

```
model <- naiveBayes(class ~ ., data=train, laplace = 3)
```

or eventually

```
model <- naiveBayes(train$class ~ ., data=train[, -c("class")], laplace = 3)
```

The second variant is more or less the same as the first variant. The `.` in the RHS of the formula is expanded to 'all other variables'; so it excludes the column `class` mentioned on the LHS. (More information is in the documentation of `formula`)